# How to reliably trigger an Airflow DAG from a Java app? (No experimental API)

Tags: java, airflow

We have a problem where we want to trigger a DAG run from a Java Microservice. The only way I've seen this done from my research is through Airflow's experimental API. Doesn't seem like that's meant for production use given that the word experimental is literally in the api path. How could I trigger a DAG run from a separate Java instance running on the same machine? Is this possible?